# Meaning of विश्वासः according to Vedas

Tags: vedas

श्रद्धः means शास्रस्य गुरुवाक्यस्य विश्वासः इति श्रद्धः,
I want to know that meaning of विश्वासः according to Vedas?

Comment: It is possible to interpret Veda Vakhyas , only through Mimamsa (Science of semantics)/ their commentary. Any attempt on semantic analysis of Veda Vakhyas , by a mere 'lookup' on Nirukta /Amarakosha - Panini, would be ineffectual.